# What happens we create a nullptr and use it in a IF condition in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, null

Hi i am trying to see what happens when i create a nullptr in C++ and use it in a if statement. For example, my code is as following:
`int *p=nullptr; if(p){cout<<"Inside IF";}`

My questions are as follows:

1. What happens when we create a nullptr? I mean does a new pointer object is created that holds the value 0(as address) or something else? And if the address it holds is  0 then is that pointer pointing to a possibly valid address in the memory?
2. What is happening when we use it in the IF statement ? I mean is the IF statement checking whether the value that the pointer object holds is 0 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What happens when we create a nullptr?

You can create a null pointer, but not a `nullptr`. The keyword `nullptr` denotes a literal value, not something that can be created.

Based on your code, you meant to ask what happens when a pointer variable is assigned `nullptr`. The answer to that is that your variable becomes a [null pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers), a pointer that points to nothing and that evaluates to `false` when used in a boolean context.

> I mean does a new pointer object is created that holds the value 0(as address) or something else?

We usually think of the value of a null pointer as being zero, but technically an implementation could use a bit pattern that has some non-zero bits. As long as you do not look too closely at the compiled code, go ahead and think of null pointers as holding the address 0.

> And if the address it holds is  0 then is that pointer pointing to a possibly valid address in the memory?

The value of a null pointer must be distinct from all potentially valid memory addresses.  If `0` is possibly a valid memory address in an implementation, then that implementation must use a different bit pattern to represent null pointers. (I am not aware of any implementations that fall into this category.)

> 2. What is happening when we use it in the IF statement ?

The condition of an `if` statement is [contextually converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) to `bool`. When [converting to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions) from a pointer, the null pointer value converts to `false` and all other values convert to `true`.

> I mean is the IF statement checking whether the value that the pointer object holds is 0 or something else?

Something else (but only by a fine shade of meaning). It checks whether the value is *the null pointer value* (which is almost certainly represented by zero bits on your computer, but technically not guaranteed to be so).

Answer (score 2):

[image: I hope this answers your Question about what is actually happening]

What you said is right nullptr allocates location and gives value 0 and 0 is false in c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
    int *p=nullptr; 
    if(p){cout<<"Inside IF";}
    cout<<&p<<endl;
    cout<<p;

     }
```

Output

0x7ffc92b66710
0

Answer (score 2):

For reference:

- [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr), the null pointer literal
- [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t), the type of `nullptr`
- [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), particularly pointer to `bool` conversions.

The line

```
int *p=nullptr;
```

Creates an `int*` pointer-to-`int` with automatic storage duration. Then `nullptr` is assigned to it, and is automatically converted to the null pointer value for the `int*` pointer. It's not actually necessarily the case that this value is stored internally as `0`, although there's an implicit conversion from the integer literal `0` to the null pointer value for every pointer type.

Then, in the comparison

```
if(p){cout<<"Inside IF";}
```

There's an implicit conversion from every pointer type to `bool`, which is applied in this `if` statement. Specifically:

> Boolean conversions
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become `false`. All other values become `true`.

So `p` has the value of the null `int*` pointer, and therefore becomes `false`.